# Watir Gem with Headless on Heroku Ruby On Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, watir, headless-browser

I have developed my ROR App and I am using Watir Gem along with headless.
It works fine on my localhost but when I deploy the code to heroku production it says Firefox not installed.

Can Anyone try to help?

This is the error shown
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError (Could not find Firefox binary (os=linux). Make sure Firefox is installed or set the path manually with Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=):

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Heroku servers don't have Xvfb nor Firefox installed, you'd have to deploy somewhere else to use a headless browser.

Comment: Isn't there a way to install Xvfb or firefox on Heroku?

Comment: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError (Could not find Firefox binary (os=linux). Make sure Firefox is installed or set the path manually with Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=):